# vuejs :disabled doesn't work

Tags: vue.js

I have a problem on reactivating the button even if the conditional statement works.
it looked like the v-model wasn't communicating with the data but with a simple interpolation the value was updated.

I don't really know where I'm doing wrong on the code.

```
<template>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">{{stock.name}}
                    <small>(Price: {{stock.price}})</small>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <input v-model="quantity" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity">
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" @click="buyStock" :disabled="isDisabled">Buy</button>
                </div>
                <p>{{quantity}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: [
        "stock",
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            quantity: 0,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        buyStock() {
            const order = {
                stockId: this.stock.id,
                stockPrice: this.stock.price,
                quantity: this.quantity
            };
            console.log(order);
            this.$store.dispatch("buyStock", order);
            this.quantity = 0;
        }
    },
    computed: {
        isDisabled() {
            if (this.quantity <= 0 || !Number.isInteger(this.quantity)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `v-model` directive binds the value as a `String`. So both checks in your `isDisabled` computed will always fail.

If you want to bind `quantity` as a number, you can add the [`.number` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number) like so:

```
<input v-model.number="quantity" type="number" ... >
```

Here's a working example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { quantity: 0 }
  },
  computed: {
    isDisabled() {
      return (this.quantity <= 0 || !Number.isInteger(this.quantity)) 
    }
  }
})
```

```css
<template>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">{{stock.name}}
                    <small>(Price: {{stock.price}})</small>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="pull-left">
                    <input v-model="quantity" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity">
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" @click="buyStock" :disabled="isDisabled">Buy</button>
                </div>
                <p>{{quantity}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model.number="quantity" type="number">
  <button :disabled="isDisabled">Foo</button>
</div>
```